# Change format of dates in Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with dates in the following format:

Dec 11, 2018

Wondering is there an easy way to change the format to 11/12/2018? I know I can go through each month manually but not sure what my next step would be to switch around the month and day and add the /.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`:

```
s = pd.Series(['Dec 11, 2018'])

pd.to_datetime(s).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Output:

```
0    12/11/2018
dtype: object
```